# What is the Athena equivalent of MySQL's JSON_REMOVE?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I want to remove items from a json value, producing a new json value, within the scope of an Athena query.

MySQL has the function `JSON_REMOVE` which does this nicely.

What is the equivalent in Athena?

I have checked the documentation and found nothing:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/extracting-data-from-JSON.html

As a temporary hack, I can sometimes use a regex before parsing the json:

`REGEXP_REPLACE(json, '\"(fieldName|anotherFieldName)\":\"[^"]*\"', ''))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer is to cast JSON to MAP and then use `map_filter`, for example:

```
select map_filter(cast(json_parse(json) as map<varchar,varchar>), (k,v) -> k !='fieldName') from ...
```